# Find if a condition stays true between a range of dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, overlap

I have a "action" table::  id, type, status, created, live_at, expired_at

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------------------------+
| id        | type      | status    | created | live_at | expired_at |
| (uuid)    | (string)  | (string)  | (date)  | (date)  |  (date)    |
+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------------------------+
```

Example rows are:

```
  10f1dc79-61b7-46a4-ad66-55e2a68b7148 | FACEBOOK_SOCIAL_SHARE | EXPIRED | 2019-06-21 11:28:31 | 2019-07-21 11:28:36 | 2019-10-02 11:40:27 
  3e59ccd4-a795-4e74-b841-4da1e57fb51f | FACEBOOK_SOCIAL_SHARE | LIVE    | 2019-10-04 18:25:57 | 2019-10-04 18:25:57 | NULL
```

I have to run a query where I get all live actions grouped by type and month.

Example Result:

```
TYPE                    MONTH LIVE
FACEBOOK_SOCIAL_SHARE     7     1
FACEBOOK_SOCIAL_SHARE     8     1
FACEBOOK_SOCIAL_SHARE     9     5
FACEBOOK_SOCIAL_SHARE     10    9
```

The problem is if an action went live in month 8 and expired some day in month of 10, then the query should count that action as live in the month 8, 9 and 10 also.

I have a query but it would only count this action as live in the month of 8!

```
SELECT TYPE, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM action.live_at) AS month, count(distinct(action.id)) AS live
FROM "action" AS action
WHERE action.live_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY TYPE, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM action.live_at)
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What about when an action goes live in November and Expires in February? Do you want to take account of the year change?

Comment: Year change does not matter. The action should be counted as live in month of November, December, January and February

Comment: @SalmanA No I don't.

Comment: @blaze never mind, it is not required.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct`is **not** a function. Putting a column between parentheses won't change the way distinct works. `distinct a` is absolutely identical to `distinct (a)`

Comment: Is the example result based on the sample data? Where do the values 5 and 9 come from then?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the info about distinct and no the result is not based on the sample data. Its just a sample of how the result is supposed to look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, I think the following will do what you want:

```sql
with actions as (
  select id, type, 
         array(select extract(month from x.dt)::int
               from generate_series(date_trunc('month', live_at), 
                                    date_trunc('month', coalesce(expired_at, current_timestamp)) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day', 
                                    interval '1 month') as x(dt)) as months_live
  from  action
)
select m.month, type, count(distinct a.id)
from generate_series(1,12) as m(month)
  left join actions a on m.month = any(a.months_live)
group by m.month, type;
```

The CTE generates an array of all months for each row in the `action` table. So for your two sample rows this would return

```
id                                   | months_live
-------------------------------------+------------
10f1dc79-61b7-46a4-ad66-55e2a68b7148 | {7,8,9,10} 
3e59ccd4-a795-4e74-b841-4da1e57fb51f | {10,11}
```

The expression `date_trunc('month', coalesce(expired_at, current_timestamp)) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day'` yields the last day of the month that `expired_at` contains. That's necessary so that `generate_series()` includes that month as well.

I don't now how a `null` value in the `expired_at` column should be treated - the above expressions simply uses "today" then.

The outer query then does an outer join between a list of 12 months and the actions - as the join condition is based on the array, a row from the actions table is repeated several times because the join condition matches multiple times.

The outer join (without grouping) returns the following rows (based on your two sample rows and today being a day in November):

```
month | type                  | id                                  
------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------
    1 |                       |                                     
    2 |                       |                                     
    3 |                       |                                     
    4 |                       |                                     
    5 |                       |                                     
    6 |                       |                                     
    7 | FACEBOOK_SOCIAL_SHARE | 10f1dc79-61b7-46a4-ad66-55e2a68b7148
    8 | FACEBOOK_SOCIAL_SHARE | 10f1dc79-61b7-46a4-ad66-55e2a68b7148
    9 | FACEBOOK_SOCIAL_SHARE | 10f1dc79-61b7-46a4-ad66-55e2a68b7148
   10 | FACEBOOK_SOCIAL_SHARE | 10f1dc79-61b7-46a4-ad66-55e2a68b7148
   10 | FACEBOOK_SOCIAL_SHARE | 3e59ccd4-a795-4e74-b841-4da1e57fb51f
   11 | FACEBOOK_SOCIAL_SHARE | 3e59ccd4-a795-4e74-b841-4da1e57fb51f
   12 |                       |
```

This result is then grouped by month and type to be able to count the IDs.

So your two sample rows would return:

```
month | type                  | count
------+-----------------------+------
    1 |                       |     0
    2 |                       |     0
    3 |                       |     0
    4 |                       |     0
    5 |                       |     0
    6 |                       |     0
    7 | FACEBOOK_SOCIAL_SHARE |     1
    8 | FACEBOOK_SOCIAL_SHARE |     1
    9 | FACEBOOK_SOCIAL_SHARE |     1
   10 | FACEBOOK_SOCIAL_SHARE |     2
   11 | FACEBOOK_SOCIAL_SHARE |     1
   12 |                       |     0
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/NYUV51842

If you need that very often, consider writing a function:

```sql
create or replace function get_month_list(p_start timestamp, p_end timestamp)  
  returns int[]
as
$$
 select array(select extract(month from x.dt)::int
              from generate_series(date_trunc('month', p_start), 
                            date_trunc('month', coalesce(p_end, current_timestamp)) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day', 
                            interval '1 month') as x(dt));
$$ 
language sql
immutable;
```

Then the query is a bit easier to read:

```sql
select m.month, type, count(distinct a.id)
from generate_series(1,12) as m(month)
  left join action a on m.month = any(get_month_list(a.live_at, a.expired_at))
group by m.month, type;
```